# lookup usernames

Tags: django

I am working on creating a page for each user, how do i lookup a username in my django user model

```
views.py
    def user_page(request,user):
    user = User.objects.filter(user =user.username)
    return render_to_response('user_page.html',"user":user,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def user_page(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    return render_to_response('user_page.html',{"user":user},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_page(request,username):
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render_to_response('user_page.html',{"user":user},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```